# is < map > threadsafe for read/write at different locations?

Tags: c++

> I remember that someone tell me, if I had a map,which already has
>   "key1" and "key2"，then using thread1 to read key1, and thread2 to
>   write "key2"(only to change "key2"'s value,not change "key2" to
>   "key3").That will not cause any threat or mistake.
>
> But if now the map only contain "key1" ， using thread1 to read key1,
>   and thread2 to insert "key2".That behavior will cause the change of
>   hash structure,so I need to add a lock.

Is that correct?

```
By the way,what about the unordered_map?Is it still the same?
```

Comment: What does the documentation for the implementation of `std::map` that you're using say? Reading is generally safe, but you must check to be sure.

Comment: No, it is not threadsafe, and will likely [make demons fly out of your nose](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html). None of the containers in the C++ library are threadsafe. It doesn't matter whether the keys are different, or not. If something modifies a container, it is not threadsafe. Full stop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is that correct?

Yes, it is correct. Both for ordered and unordered standard maps.

Although, there is no "hash structure" in an ordered map, and it is not possible to change the key of an element in either container.

Comment: “I remember that someone tell me, if I had a map,which already has "key1" and "key2"，then using thread1 to read key1, and thread2 to write "key2"(only to change "key2"'s value,not change "key2" to "key3").That will not cause any threat or mistake.”   so that part was true？

Comment: @scirocc Yes, and also the second paragraph.